# LWGJL Blending Issues

Tags: opengl, libgdx, alpha, lighting

I'm trying to use a lightmap to create an effect like this, but doing it only with blending functions and rendering: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JkyGTZ0992s

Basically, have the light map have 100% transparency when it's all white and have it fade off from there, as you can see in the video above.

Right now, it's blending, but it's very dark as you can see from the picture (ignore starbound art): https://gyazo.com/fa0cecbe6085db3dc15291a86396af13

Is this because of my blending modes? I can't figure it out, hopefully you can! Thanks!

CODE:

```
public ShaderProgram shader;
public Texture texture;
public Sprite sprite;

public Sprite lightSprite;
public Texture lightText;
public ShapeRenderer shape;
SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

@Override
public void create() {
    shape = new ShapeRenderer();
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
    texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("image.png"));
    sprite = new Sprite(texture);

    lightText = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("light.png"));
    lightSprite = new Sprite(lightText);

    ShaderProgram.pedantic = false;
    shader = new ShaderProgram(Gdx.files.internal("shaders/passthrough.vert"), Gdx.files.internal("shaders/passthrough.frag"));
    System.out.println(shader.getLog());

    spriteBatch.setShader(shader);
}

@Override
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    /*
    Draw image
     */
    spriteBatch.setShader(shader);
    spriteBatch.begin();
    sprite.draw(spriteBatch);


    spriteBatch.setShader(null);
    spriteBatch.setBlendFunction(GL30.GL_DST_COLOR, GL30.GL_SRC_ALPHA);
    lightSprite.draw(spriteBatch, 1.0f);
    spriteBatch.end();
    lightSprite.setPosition(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY());
    spriteBatch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
}
```

}`

The shader I'm using just makes the screen darker, here that is too:
VERT: http://pastebin.com/LkxCZGf6
FRAG: http://pastebin.com/dLwudnHx

lightmap: [image]

Comment: youtube video removed, pastebin link expired. Your question really shouldn't rely on external links if at all avoidable

Comment: I'm sorry! I attached the correct video.